# Auto increment number for multiple lines in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, selection, increment, emmet

How to achieve auto increment for multiple selection in PhpStorm ie. If I have lines like this selected or taged with multiple cursors

```
my line das
my line asd
my line sda
my line poi
my line uio
my line kjy
```

And I want to have them automatically numbered like this

```
my line das 1
my line asd 2 
my line sda 3 
my line poi 4
my line uio 5
my line kjy 6
```

Is there any simple method to this with Emmet or any other plugin?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124616 ?

Comment: @LazyOne Yup, this is totally what I mean, so I see that I have to use Sublime Text to do this with plugin Text Pastry.

Comment: Some workaround, but works and can be used also for more complex edit - just use excel sheet with any increment formula that you want. Then copy column with values and paste with multiline editing in intellij :-)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Update: This feature is now available in the [String Manipulation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162?pr=idea) plugin v4.5**

*Old:* It's far from ideal, but you can use the `Duplicate and increment` action from the `String Manipulation` plugin. It's quite easy to do and it does the job:

[image]

Add a shortcut to this action or execute it multiple time to increment a line containing a number.

So far no PhpStorm plugin allows to do exactly what to describe.

It may be the occasion to [create one](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started.html) !

Comment: Not really -- his lines have different text (check the word before the numbers).

Comment: start at the end of the first line. Ctrl, hold ctrl, press down until you reach the bottom, now you have a multiselect line. Then type '0' and you will have a bunch of zeros. Press shift+left to select them all, then ctrl+shift+a (commands) and type 'Create Sequence' and finally kaboom! You have a series of digits!

Comment: In order to use the Create Sequence command you first need to go to `Settings -> Plugins -> Browser Repositories -> Search: "String Manipulation"` and install it. Then you will have access to the Create Sequence command using the Ctrl+Shift+A hotkey.

Answer (score 10):

1. **String Manipulation** is the name of the addon (as already mentioned by [Xedecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36445288/auto-increment-number-for-multiple-lines-in-phpstorm/58597066#comment65809225_36477843)).
2. **Create sequence** is the name of the action you want to use. (This does *exactly* what you want!)

Or use [InputSequence](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16304-inputsequence) another plugin for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want put I had to increment about 100 lines of code so I went to repl.it and spat this out, copied and pasted.

```
for(let i = 235; i < 340; i++){
  console.log(`case "board_1_${i}":
  return board_1_${i};`)
}
```

Comment: This works but is not effective. I do not recommend using workarounds for things an IDE should provide.